# How Find a value as any Data Type by searching all tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server
I want to have search anywhere in my query

for example :
I want to search this '123' value in whole Database

Search not only strings also numbers : '123' and 123
for each column according to its type

please guide me

Comment: I find it add that if you are using SQL Server 2014, you added the tags of three *other* versions, leaving out the version you are actually using.

Comment: Effectively an [exact dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66223111/how-do-i-find-a-text-with-any-data-type-in-all-tables-of-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment117080329_66223111); I smell a sock puppet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query. I have tried and found working awesomely.

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchStr = '201902'
 
 
    -- Copyright © 2002 Narayana Vyas Kondreddi. All rights reserved.
    -- Purpose: To search all columns of all tables for a given search string
    -- Written by: Narayana Vyas Kondreddi
    -- Site: http://vyaskn.tripod.com
    -- Updated and tested by Tim Gaunt
    -- http://www.thesitedoctor.co.uk
    -- http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2010/02/19/Search+Every+Table+And+Field+In+A+SQL+Server+Database+Updated.aspx
    -- Tested on: SQL Server 7.0, SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2010
    -- Date modified: 03rd March 2011 19:00 GMT
    CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))
 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
 
    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
    SET  @TableName = ''
    SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')
 
    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
     
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                        OBJECT_ID(
                            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                             ), 'IsMSShipped'
                               ) = 0
        )
 
        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
             
        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName =
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                    AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                    AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                    AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
            )
     
            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
             
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                )
            END
        END   
    END
 
    SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
 
DROP TABLE #Results
```

I have found this in below link. You will also find a store procedure to do so.
https://thesitedoctor.co.uk/blog/search-every-table-and-field-in-a-sql-server-database-updated/

Comment: thanks so much but this is for string I want to have search for any data type

Comment: It works for numbers too. SET @SearchStr = 1 will do the same trick. I tried and found working.

Comment: How can I add it WHERE LIKE N'%value%' ?

Comment: for '%value%' you will assign just value like SET @SearchStr = '201902'. Please share a table with a value you want to search. If this query is not returning that I will try to modify that .

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. It simply loop all the required tables-column combinations and returns the matched results.

```
-- creating a temp table to fetch all tables in scope
drop table if exists #TMP_TABLE ;
create table #TMP_TABLE (
    PK INT IDENTITY,
    TABLE_NAME varchar(500),
    COLUMN_NAME varchar(500),
    IS_EXIST bit
)


INSERT INTO #TMP_TABLE (TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME)
SELECT C.TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
WHERE -- C.TABLE_NAME = <your-tables> AND 
    C.DATA_TYPE in( 'varchar', 'int'); -- modify it to handle data types at once.

declare @MINID int, @MAXID int, @TABLE_NAME varchar(500), @COLUMN_NAME varchar(500), @sqlString varchar(max);
-- setting boundaries for the while loop
SET @MINID = (SELECT ISNULL(MIN(PK),0) FROM #TMP_TABLE ); 
SET @MAXID = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(PK),0) FROM #TMP_TABLE );

-- looping all the table-columns in scope
WHILE ((@MINID<=@MAXID) AND (@MINID<>0))
BEGIN
    SELECT @TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME,@COLUMN_NAME =  COLUMN_NAME
    FROM  #TMP_TABLE 
    WHERE PK = @MINID;

    SET @sqlString =  'UPDATE #TMP_TABLE 
                    SET IS_EXIST = 1 
                    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                        FROM '+ @TABLE_NAME+' 
                        WHERE  '+ @COLUMN_NAME +' = ''<YOUR-SEARCH-STRING>'') 
                        AND PK = '+ CAST(@MINID AS varchar(10));
    EXEC(@sqlString) ;
    SET @MINID = (SELECT MIN(PK) FROM #TMP_TABLE WHERE PK > @MINID );
END 

SELECT * FROM #TMP_TABLE WHERE IS_EXIST = 1 ; -- will give you matched results.
```

Comment: thanks but can you make a sample for this ?

Comment: updated with a working code. Hope it helps.